# Syntax to chain multiple fields together that are all a part of the same return object

Tags: c#

If I had a method like below:

```
public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
  // code that returns a Person where id is == id
}
```

Let's also so that Person looks like this:

```
public class Person 
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string firstName {get; set;}
   public string lastName {get;set}
}
```

I know that I could call it like so:

```
string name = GetPerson(someId).firstName;
```

What is the syntax where I could *chain* the firstName and lastName together? I am aware that some of the answers might be, "just create a field `fullName`" but I am actually just trying to expand my knowledge of C# to see if there is a way to chain those fields together WITHOUT doing this:

```
string name = $"{GetPerson(someId).firstName} {GetPerson(someId).lastName}";
```

Also, I don't want to return the Person object and then combine them. I'd like to (if it is possible) just combine it all in one line with chaining. I've tried several ways and can't get it to compile.

**Edit**
What original prompted me to want to do this was to avoid calling the GetPerson method 2x when using a concatenation approach to getting the full name (when not just creating a variable for this purpose). As was pointed out in the comments by Servy, this is really what variables are for and, as was also pointed out by O. R. Mapper, what I was looking for does not appear to be supported by C# at this time.

Comment: Store the person in a variable.  This is exactly what they exist for.

Comment: What do you mean by "chain"?

Comment: Why not just add a full name property on the object that uses string interpolation or `string.Format` to join the full name?

Comment: Alright, ignore the first part of my comment - after seeing your message regarding the `fullName` property, but now my question is why are you trying to "expand knowledge" by adding complication? Even the most experienced developers would use a property, otherwise you're adding complication for the sake of adding complication.

Comment: @DStanley Nothing at all. As my question states, its just a language question and not a proper-way-to-do-something or practicality question. No panda bears will be saved or lost by this question being answered :-)

Comment: Further to the comments, OP could add "in X language, I would do this: `showUsHowYouWouldDoIt();`" to his post, so it becomes more clear what he's after.

Comment: @trashr0x: As far as I understood, the OP is looking for some syntax such as `string name = with GetPerson(someId) { firstName + " " + lastName }` (which would then return the expression in the braces, with identifiers evaluated in the scope `GetPerson(someId)`). I do not think anything to that effect is currently supported by C#, though.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you **really** want to do that in one line, you can use extension method which will apply to any object, like this:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static TResult Select<T, TResult>(this T target, Func<T, TResult> selector) {
        return selector(target);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
GetPerson(1).Select(p => p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
```

Comment: But this *is* explicitly declaring variables, the variables are just parameters to a method instead of a local variable, but they're both variables.

Comment: But you do.  `p`.  It's a variable of type `Person`, that you've declared.

Comment: Well anyway author just wants to explore options, and this is one option. However I removed a note about explicit variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.format`

```
Person person = GetPerson(someId);
string.Format("{0} {1}", person.firstName, person.lastName);
```

Comment: Now you're getting the person twice, rather than once.  Also, this isn't really any different than the OP's code, and has all of the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

STart with answering the question: How would the program consume the chained together first and last names?

For starters, you could

1. Create another field

> ```
> string FullName
> {
>    get 
>       { 
>          return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
>       }
> }
> ```

Pros: It is readonly and solely based on the values in the class. 
Cons: It is another field and causes you to violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (meaning a different reason for the class to change, in this case formatting versus a data container).

1. Create a separate class that implements the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that would then change the appearance (formatting) of the Person class to whatever you like. For example:

   ```
   public interface IPersonFormatter
   {
           string asFullName();                 // Returns "firstName lastName";
           string asCSVRecord();                  // Returns "id,firstName,lastName" to be imported to Excel
   }

   public class ConcretePersonFormatter : IPersonFormatter
   {
           //Members
           private Person _personInstance;

           public ConcretePersonFormatter(Person p)
           {
                   _personInstance = p;
           }

           //IPersonFormatter implementation
           string asFullName()
           {
                   return _personInstance.firstName + " " + _personInstance.lastName;
           }

           string asCSVRecord()
           {
                   return _personInstance.id + "," + _personInstance.firstName + "," + _personInstance.lastName;
           }
   }
   ```

Then create a ConcretePersonFormatter instance, and pass your instance of Person to it, then call the methods shown above

Answer (score 0):

As I understood what you mean you can make property on your person class

```
string fullname
{
    get
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

So it would be:

```
GetPerson(someId).fullname;
```

Comment: Read the question.